# playing video by clicking a href from database with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

im new to laravel and i want to play my video by clicking  but, i cant play the video no matter what. pls suggest what im doing wrong.

here is my coding

```
 @foreach($video as $v)
     <a href="{{$v->linkvideo}}" class="next-video">
       <img src="{{$v->linkimage}}" alt="">
        <h3 class="single-video-title">{{$v->tittle}}</h3>
     </a>
 @endforeach
```

i already tried tag source and i frame, but it only make the view messy

Comment: Where's the `<video>` tag of the video that you want to play? As there seems to be just a link redirecting to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

make another route for playing videos and pass the video url to that route and show the video in another blade using html video tag